# AEM 6.2 SP1 not supporting Java 8 Lambda Expressions. Rest of the Java 8 features e.g. Stream are working

Tags: java-8, aem, maven-plugin, osgi-bundle, sling

I am using AEM 6.2 SP1 with Java 8. If I write any Java 8 lambda expression in any of the Java class; the application fails - throwing a NullPointerException i.e. ResourceResolverFactory is null. The lambda expression has nothing to do with the ResourceResolverFactory and written in a completely different class.

But Strangely, If I use any other Java 8 features e.g. Stream, Optional etc. it works fine without any issue.

We are using maven-bundle-plugin(3.0.1) to create OSGI bundles to deploy in AEM felix container. All the bundles are in Active state.But if lambdas are written the bundles does not work properly resulting to NullpointerException

Please help me with this issue. How to make AEM support lambda expressions.

Comment: there must be a stacktrace attached with the exception you've noticed and that can help you look into the cause better.

Comment: Can you please provide the snippet of code that fails?

Comment: See I have mentioned the code where null pointer exception occurs has nothing to do with this lambda. When I am writing a lambda expression in a class ; the application fails saying ResourceResolverFactory is null. Now this ResourceResolverFactory is injected via spring. ResourceResolverFactory ref is created by osgi:service.  This application is a working live application; We were trying to implement lambda for a requirement and then observe this behaviour. Without this lambda everything works fine. I have tested with some dummy lambdas like squaring a dummy variable x ; even that fails

Comment: The fun part is the class where i have written the dummy lambda gets executed on a different flow. Application fails in the home page itself where there are no reference of the affected class. The build is successful and even i checked on the bundles ,they are also active

Comment: According to apache maven-bundle-plugin from version 2.4.0 started supporting Lambda expressions. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-4005. However in my project I am using maven -bundle-plugin -3.0.1. Still facing this issue.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just some error in the code of your lambda expression? Have you tried reproducing the issue with a really trivial lambda?

Comment: I am writing a really trivial lambda like - Consumer<String> c = (x) -> System.out.println(x.toLowerCase());
    c.accept("Java2s.com");

Comment: It is hard for us to understand what you are facing without us being able to reproduce. I'd suggest setting up a new simple project that reproduces the issue, pushing it to github and linking here so we can help you further.